# WAMP - phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, apache, wamp

Was hoping I could get some help with WAMP.

I have installed WAMP 2.5 on a Windows 7 machine with the intention of testing wordpress.

I am able to navigate to index.php from here I press phpMyAdmin and it just loads a blank page

The service is running on port 80.

In WAMP >Apache > Service > Test Port 80 i receive the message **" Your Port 80 is actually used by Apache 2.4.9   PHP/5.5.12**

This tells me that the port is open and Apache is running on the port.

I have tried various combinations of

```
http://localhost:80/myphpadmin

127.0.0.1:80/myphpadmin
```

I have checked my local hosts file and have the below

```
127.0.0.1       localhost

::1
```

Apache HTTPD.CONF

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80
```

Comment: Do you have JavaScript enabled? Also, you've spelt it wrong in your attempts, it's **phpmyadmin** not myphpadmin: `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`

Comment: A blank page could point to a serverside error. Look at the error log of your apache.

Answer (score 0):

try "localhost/phpmyadmin" from a default installation of wamp you do not need to specify the port unless you have setup a vhost or other specific configurations of Apache service on a different port than 80.

Answer (score 0):

Your HOSTS file should look like this

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1  localhost
```